# C# Web Api Routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Goal: I want to define REST verb names and link them to the REST routes. Next, I want to map custom rules to a defined action name:

```
GET / => Get()
GET /1 => Get(int id)
POST / => Post()
PUT / => Put()
DELETE /1 => Delete(int id)
GET /custom => [HttpGet][ActionName("custom")] GetCustom()
```

I have in OwinStartup.cs:

```
httpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute (
    name: "ControllerWithId",
    routeTemplate: "rest/{controller}/{id}",
    constraints: new {
        id = @"^\d+$"
    },
    defaults: new {
        action = "Index",
        id = RouteParameter.Optional
});
httpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute (
    name: "ControllerWithAction",
    routeTemplate: "rest/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {
        action = "Index",
        id = RouteParameter.Optional
    });
```

I have an ApiController:

```
public class MyController : ApiController {
    public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> Get() {}
    public async Task<object> Get(int id) {}
    public async Task Post([FromBody] data) {}
    public async Task Put(int id, [FromBody] data) {}
    public async Task Delete(int id) {}
    [HttpGet][ActionName("custom")]
    public async Task Custom() {}
}
```

They all return 404 except for custom. It would suck to have to add an ActionName to each REST method. What is the most concise solution?

Comment: Why don't you use attribute routing? And you should return implementations of `IHttpActionResult` instead of a `Task` *as is*

Comment: I thought of that but wanted to use the default naming convention / or to do it the "right way".

Comment: @Exegesis If the below post worked for you then you should accept it as answer so that other people would prefer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC doesn't provide an easy method using their named conventions for CRUD/custom endpoints. I went the ugly route and explicitly specified `ActionName("")` for each CRUD method.

reyan-chougle's solution requires you to hardcode strings in your code which is bad practice. I tried to add magic strings to the attributes but got compiler errors.

Solution:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName (Consts.defaultActionMethdName)]
    public IEnumerable<Model> Get () {}

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName (Consts.defaultActionMethdName)]
    public Model Get (int id) {}

    [ActionName (Consts.defaultActionMethdName)]
    public IHttpActionResult Post ([FromBody] Model input) {}

    [ActionName (Consts.defaultActionMethdName)]
    public IHttpActionResult Put (int id, [FromBody] Model input) {}

    [ActionName (Consts.defaultActionMethdName)]
    public IHttpActionResult Delete (int id) {}

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("custom")]
    public async Task Custom() {}
```